# How to split value from a string and push into array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to split value from string and push into an array but not working. How to do it in javascript?

```
var values="test1,test2,test3,test4,test5";

var arrP=[];

var newVal=values.split(',');

arrP.push(newVal);

console.log(arrP);
```

Output should be,

```
arrP=["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"];
```

Comment: The result you'd like should be already into `newVal`, as `split` does exactly what you need.

Comment: Try and log `newVal`.

Comment: `arrP.push(...newVal)` or `arrP = arraP.concat(newVal);` but only if arrayP have already elements if it's empty you don't need to do anything just `arrP = values.split(',');`

Comment: `var arrP=values.split(',');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var values="test1,test2,test3,test4,test5";
var arrP = [];
var newVal = values.split(',');
arrP.push(...newVal);
console.log(arrP);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an array to an already existing array, use concat.

```
var values="test1,test2,test3,test4,test5";

var arrP=[];

var newVal=values.split(',');

arrP = arrP.concat(newVal);

console.log(arrP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a split on `,`. Because `split()`, divides a String into an ordered set of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array and that's what you want

```js
var values="test1,test2,test3,test4,test5";
var expected = values.split(',');
console.log(expected)
```

With your existing code you will get with extra `[]` at start and end,

```
[["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]]
```

But I guess you want this,

```
["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet `var newVal=values.split(',');` will create a new array since split creates a new array. So your code is pushing an array to another array

```js
var values = "test1,test2,test3,test4,test5";
var newVal = values.split(',');
console.log(newVal);
```

To fix that you need to iterate that array and push those values. If `map` is used then no need to declare an array since map returns a new array

```js
var values = "test1,test2,test3,test4,test5".split(',').map(item => item)
console.log(values);
```